# image either big or small in html

Tags: android, html, css

i trying to create an webapp for android, the problem is the dropdown list box which i can't get it in same width as image on the top which has 600 x 225. the width of the list box is way longer than the width of the  image.Can anyone suggest anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including some code would help a lot. This might work though:

```
select#myid {

    width:600px;

}
```

Change `myid` to whatever id you have set the dropdown.

Comment: thanks, that did the trick. by doing this, will this auto adjust the width according to the phone screen?

Comment: It won't. When you set a width to any number of px, you are setting it absolutely. If you want it you adjust, you either have to set it in terms of percentage (100%, 80%), or use media queries to change what width is being applied based on how wide the screen is.

Comment: @user2199351 Since he did a great job answering your question I thought I would add something that was really useful for me.  Using fluid images.  http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images

Comment: really appreciate the help andy and thanks for the link camdixon